# rCharts to Wordpress using knit2wp

Tags: r, wordpress, knitr, rcharts

I have been trying to [publish an rChart](http://ramnathv.github.io/rCharts/r2js/) into my blog using the `knit2wp` function. However, locally I can get the chart to render but when I publish it the chart becomes just text...

I have a Rmd file that goes like this:

```
library(rCharts)
r1 <- rPlot(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars, type = 'point')
r1$print('inline', cdn = TRUE,include_assets = TRUE)
```

or

```
r1$print('iframesrc', cdn = TRUE)
```

To publish I use this:

```
knit2wp('test.Rmd',
        title = 'test',
        options(WordpressLogin = c(LOGIN = 'PASS'),
                WordpressURL =     'https://dadosdadosdados.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php'),
        shortcode =  c(TRUE, TRUE),
        publish = F)
```